# In Episode 2, how did Mark get up the stairs?

Tags: the-walking-dead-season-one

### This question is spoilerific! Read at your own peril!

> In the Walking Dead: Episode 2, it turns out the St. John family are cannibals and eat survivors, and Mark's legs are the main course of the meal. You see a legless Mark crawling around on the main floor of the house just after Lee tells everyone to stop eating. Later on Lee confronts the mother of the St. John family, who is holding a gun to Katjaa's head. She slowly backs up the stairs as you approach, and near the top of the stairs gets grabbed by a walker who is stuck at the top of the staircase.

I immediately assumed this walker was Mark because:

1. it was trapped, and all we could see was its arms, so its legs weren't functioning.
2. We'd seen Mark dying due to blood loss 10 minutes before, so it could be him.
3. How would a random walker get upstairs and trapped without anyone else noticing?

> If this was legless Mark, why and how did he get up the stairs? No legs means no stairs. Did someone put him up there, or was this simply a stray walker who magically appeared upstairs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To confirm your suspicions,

> Yes, that walker was most definitely Mark.

That said, according to [Mark's wikia page](http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/Mark_(Video_Game)):

> It was never explicitly shown what happened to Mark during this time, but it was implied that the St. Johns simply dragged him back upstairs where they kept him alive.

He was up there to begin with so that he could be kept alive, so it would make sense that they brought him back up there.

> The reason for this, as later explained by Danny St. John, is that the family's victims were kept alive so the meat didn't become "tainted." The evidence to support this came from the assortment of medical instruments and supplies, found earlier in the dairy house, which were specifically designed to keep a person living for as long as possible.

Comment: That sounds reasonable. The St. John's must've gotten REALLY sloppy though, letting him die, while also not securing the room they put him in. Oh well. Revenge is sweet.

Comment: @DeeCeptor, IIRC, Lee was suspicious and began looking for Mark when he stumbled upon him in the bathroom, so it wasn't necessarily the St. Johns' fault that he was able to get out. I think they were more focused on Lee and the others and didn't restrain Mark as well as before when he'd escaped the second time.